# Convexity Bound of Rankin-Selberg L-Function

Tags: convex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms, l-functions

Let $f,g$ be primitive modularforms of arbitrary levels $N_1,N_2$, trivial nebentypus and same weight $k$. Let $L(f\otimes g,s)=\zeta(2s)\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\lambda_f(n)\lambda_g(n)}{n^s}$ be the Rankin-Selberg L-Function where $\lambda_f$ and $\lambda_g$ are the respective normalized Hecke-Eigenvalues.

I'm looking for a simple upper bound of $L(f\otimes g,\frac12+it)$ in the level aspect which holds under general assumptions as given above. In nearly every piece of literature on subconvexity bounds (e.g. Introduction of "Rankin Selberg L-functions in the level aspect" by Kowalski, Michel, Vanderkam) there is the hint that the convexity bound ($\sqrt N$ in the level aspect, $k$ in the weight aspect) is achieved by applying the Phragmén-Lindelöf principle. As far as I understood, this requires another bound of the function on the edges of the vertical strip $0<\Re(s)<1$. So my questions are

- Is there an elementary proof to this problem?
- What bound can I use for $L(f\otimes g, 1)$?
- How do I take care of the residue in $s=1$ for $f=\overline{g}$?

Comment: I'd say : add finitely many Euler factors to $L(f\otimes g, s)$ to obtain a Dirichlet series $H(s)$ with functional equation. Obtain a bound $H(1+it) = O(\log^m(t))$ (in the same way you showed the PNT for $L(f,s)$ ?). Use the functional equation to obtain a bound for $H(it)$. Apply the convexity theorem. I don't know if the implied constants are effective. What the found for $L(f\otimes g,\frac12+it)$ would be useful for ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I use the bound as a factor for a more general result which applies not only to newforms but to arbitrary cusp forms. The readers can insert a stronger bound if they want quantitatively better results but I just need an elementarily introduced placeholder instead of a reference to an article of 30 pages about any subconvexity bound.

Comment: By the way, $L(s,f \otimes g)$ is *not* equal to $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda_f(n) \lambda_g(n)}{n^s}$. Rather, it is equal (up to some Euler factors at bad primes) to this Dirichlet series times $L(2s,\chi_f \chi_g)$, where $\chi_f, \chi_g$ are the nebentypen of $f$ and $g$.

Comment: Alright, so I need a factor of $\zeta(2s)$. Thanks for that reminder @PeterHumphries, I will watch out for that in my notation.

Comment: @reuns I define $H(s)=(2\pi)^{-2s}\Gamma(s+k-1)\Gamma(s)L(s,f\otimes g)$ which allows the functional equation $H(1-s)=H(s)$ for $f\neq g$. So for $L(f\otimes f,s)$ I need another estimation...

Comment: @reuns thanks a lot for your help, my answer merely summarizes what you already proposed. The reference contains some more details about the analytic conductor and the convexity theorem which helped me to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To provide a brief answer which can be found in "Analytic Number Theory" of Iwaniec and Kowalsky:

We use the absolute convergence of $L(f,s)$ in $\sigma>1$ (or the bound $|\lambda(n)|\leq \tau(n)$), the functional equation, Stirling's estimate for the gamma function and the Phragmen-Lindelöf convexity principle.

All mentioned formulas can be found in the book as well.